# Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object

Tags: objective-c

I have this Objective-C code

```
-(NSURL *)URL
{
    if(!_url)
    {
        if(self.viewModelData[@"url"])
            _url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.viewModelData[@"url"]];
        else
            _url = self.viewModelData[@"URL"];
    }
    return _url;
}
```

I'm getting this error and I don't understand what the problem is:

> Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'id<FLLWebViewModelData>'

Comment: `viewModelData` is a `FLLWebViewModelData` I guess? Could you share it?

Comment: Use confromsToProtocol: or respondsToProtocol: method to check whether object  implements expected protocol.